# How to get ANSI file as output of command line operation

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I run command in windows command line and redirect the output to text file:

```
echo 123 > C:\\output.txt
```

This file has Unicode encoding and I have problems with reading of it with python. How I can get ANSI file after execution of this command?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Could you try this `from __future__ import unicode_literals` before reading your file?

Comment: Can I change something in windows settings to get ANSI file instead of Unicode file after execution of co,,and in command line?

Comment: I do not know. Unfortunately, I do not have practice with Windows.

Comment: When you say Unicode do you mean UTF8 or UTF-16? Check the first 3 bytes for a BOM, e.g `"\xff\xfe"` (UTF-16LE) or `"\xef\xbb\xbf"` (UTF-8). Once you know the encoding you can open the file with `io.open(filepath, encoding=file_encoding)`.

Comment: Thanks! Issue was fixed with "codecs.open('C:\\Tests\\auto_result.txt', encoding='UTF-16LE')"

Comment: Note that `codecs.open` opens the underlying file in binary mode and decodes the raw bytes. So it doesn't do newline translation from `"\r\n"` to `"\n"`. Use `io.open` (backported from Python 3) to get newline translation in text mode.

Comment: By default, `echo 123 > file.txt` will be ANSI encoded.  I can only assume you changed the console code page.